# Having issues sending "base64" email "attachments" using "@sendgrid/mail" in "nodejs"

Tags: node.js, express, email, sendgrid, nodemailer

So, basically I want to send a base64 encoded .zip file as email attachment in @sendgrid/mail. The file is saved in MongoDB like this,
[image]

I am fetching the data and converting the "file.buffer" which is a binary data to base64 using .toString("base64") something like this,

```js
console.log('Converting to base64')
plugin.file.buffer = plugin.file.buffer.toString('base64')
```

and it gets perfectly converted into base64 (I know it is working because I am also using that "plugin.file" in .ejs file as a download button something like this,

```html
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" download="plugin.zip" href="data:application/zip;base64,<%- plugin %>" role="button">Download</a>
```

So, now I will be using that "plugin" to send a email to the user, so I am doing something like this just before rendering the ejs page,

```js
if (req.session.email) await sendMail(req.session.email , "Thanks for purchasing" , "Here is your delivery!" , plugin)
res.render('success' , {payment , type: "Payment" , discord , plugin: plugin.file.buffer})
```

It basically checks if the email of the user is stored in "sessions" i.e. logged in, if yes it sends a email and then renders the success page!

So, the issue is in the email.js file sendMail() function. It is neither sending me the email nor the attachment.

Before showing the code inside that function(), my api keys etc are correct as I am also sending a mail whenever the user creates an account and in that case, everything is working fine and the mail is being sent. But whenever I include the attachment logic, neither the mail nor the attachment is being sent! So, here is my code:-

```js
const { MAILER_API_KEY } = require('../config.json')
const mailer = require('@sendgrid/mail')
mailer.setApiKey(MAILER_API_KEY)

async function sendMail(email , subject , text , plugin) {
    mailOptions = {
        to: email,
        from: 'zoomdev.code@gmail.com',
        subject: subject,
        text: text
    }

    // if this if statement is false i.e. plugin is undefined(whenever the user is signing up, he/she doesnt need attachment or stuff. The attachment email is being sent whenever the payment is completed and the file is being sent to the user) it works fine. But sending an attachment doesn't work. The email and attachment doesn't get sent!
    if (plugin) mailOptions.attachments = [{
        content: plugin.file.buffer,
        filename: plugin.file.originalname,
        type: 'application/zip', // Here, I have also tried using "application/x-zip-compressed", the type saved in the database and it is the same! :(
        disposition: 'attachment'
    }]

    await mailer.send(mailOptions).then(res => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
        return true
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        return false
    })
    console.log('Mail sent to ' + email)
}

module.exports = { sendMail }
```

Whenever sending the attachment email, I am getting this in console,

```js
Executing Payment
Converting to base64
Updating user
// ^ these are something else. Ignore them

// this is the JSON.stringify(... console.log in sendMail function last lines
[{"statusCode":202,"body":"","headers":{"server":"nginx","date":"Fri, 22 Oct 2021 06:57:18 GMT","content-length":"0","connection":"close","x-message-id":"QpxSudqkRGytDU7YFleVgA","access-control-allow-origin":"https://sendgrid.api-docs.io","access-control-allow-methods":"POST","access-control-allow-headers":"Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl","access-control-max-age":"600","x-no-cors-reason":"https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html","strict-transport-security":"max-age=600; includeSubDomains"}},""]
Mail sent to <my email , I have edited this part for privacy, but it correctly logs the email>
```

Note:-

1. I am using express@^4.17.1
2. @sendgrid/mail@^7.4.7
3. I have checked spam folder and everything

Comment: In your code the email address you are sending from is a Gmail address. Is that the same email you are using when you send an email on account creation? And have you verified that email address using [Single Sender Verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification)?

Comment: Yes the email addresses are correct. Also I have mentioned that I am using the email sending feature while signing in too and it is working at that time but while sending with attachment, it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Using a Gmail address as your from address is not a good way to get your emails delivered. Doing so means you are spoofing an email address, even if it is your email address.

When you are spoofing an email address like that, the email server is unable to prove that it has permission to send emails for that address. [SPF](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/spf-records) and [DKIM](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/dkim-records) are methods you can use to prove that you control the domain the email is coming from, but when you use a Gmail address (or any other mailbox provider) then you will appear to be spoofing and receiving mailboxes may choose to discard your emails or land them in the spam inbox.

You may have managed to send and receive your account creation emails with this method, but mailbox providers will be a lot more restrictive when it comes to receiving emails with attached zip files. The whole thing appears suspicious and the mailbox will likely reject it, send it spam, or silently delete it.

The advice here is just [don't send emails from a domain that you don't control](https://sendgrid.com/blog/dont-send-email-from-domains-you-dont-control/). What you should do is get a domain that you want to send emails from, [set up domain authentication for that domain](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) and you will have a much better chance of landing your emails in your users' inboxes than by spoofing Gmail.